# Azure webapp instances

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, webforms

I'm new to azure and cloud platform development - I have a web application and I create multiple companies using a

**company** table and 
seperate the 
**company_products** using a foreign key: **companyid**

Is it possible to run multiple instances in which each has it's own SQL database? I want to do this because every customer is unique and they may need tailored modules.

Comment: Why not have different slots under one web app, and have them pointing to different databases that you create? I work with Azure and I have a single web app, with about 4 slots all in production. Sure there's a performance degradation but it still gets the job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no restrictions on how you build your app. You many create as many databases as you wish, and have multiple web apps if you wish (whether in the same app service plan or across multiple app service plans). How you do this is strictly up to you, but no - there is nothing that forces you to use a single database for anything.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you would like each of your customers to have their own instance and separate databases?

Have a look at this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff966499.aspx

I'd suggest using Azure App Service, and running each of your customers in their own app.  You can save money as all the apps run under the same App Service Plan.  Usage on one instance however, does not affect performance on another.  There are quite a lot of benefits with App Service.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview/

For starting out, I'd suggest using individual Azure SQL Databases for each customer.  This is to save money, as you can spin up S0/S1 databases for relatively cheap.  Then you can set the connection string through the Azure Portal for each app you have under your App Service Plan.

If you end up scaling quickly, have a look at Elastic Databases.  You pay for a database server and get something like 200 databases per server.  So its really only economical if you have quite a few customers and can justify the cost.  However there are some useful Azure tools that make managing elastic database pools easier.  Check out the Azure documentation for more details on this.

Once you have this architecture set up, you can either manage your instances/databases through the portal or setup another logic app to manage all your instances.  It would be a lot less development work to just manage it through the portal for starting out, however if this is a SaaS product, and is going to scale quite quickly, you may want to invest ahead of time in automating some processes so that deploying new instances doesn't have to be done manually.

I prefer this approach as well, because you can then point different subdomains at your individual custom apps.  (i.e. customer1.yourdomain.com, customer2.yourdomain.com).  Each app already has it's own domain under azurewebsites.net, so if you don't mind using that domain, you can just stick with it.  It's nice cause then you don't have to manage your own DNS or worry about SSL Certificates and what not, as it's already managed for you.  If you do want your own custom domains, there's plenty of documentation on this.  Azure also has a DNS service for automating creating CNAME records while automatically spinning up a new app and deploying a DB to your pool and initializing the DB, etc...

Answer (score 0):

As David says, you can do this how you like.  My suggestion would be to use connection strings in your application's web.config to control the database instance you want to communicate with, and you can then configure your azure web app deployment's "slot settings" in the azure portal (or your ARM template) to override the web config settings for that deployment.

So - you can create your ARM template which describes your infrastructure, and may deploy your app service plan, web app, web config, sql database to a specifically named resource group (ie. targeting one of your customers).  This would have configuration that points to the database instance in that resource group, and possibly other config that turns customer specific functionality on/off.  Try to keep the code and deployment as common as you can, otherwise you'll end up with a maintenance nightmare in the future.

See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/ for information on configuration settings in azure web apps.